# Advance Excel Compare Function

Tags: excel-2010

I have an excel sheet which shows the names of 1,900 borrowers. The sheet is not sorted out in alphabetical order (and it does not need to be sorted in alphabetical order). What I am trying to perform is that I want to compare the two column and see if they match. If the two columns do not match I want that result to be shown either in separate column or those names of the countries and responsible person to be highlighted. 
For example, the below screen shot shows that there are various countries in the list and there is various responsible person associated with each country. The idea is to identify the countries whose responsible person are not the same. So in this example countries USA & AUSTRALIA should not show up because they have the same responsible person but all other countries and responsible person should be identified.  I appreciate and thanks for all the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating a pivot table of your data. Insert pivot table and then add Country name and count of responsible person as grouping (assuming no duplicates) then anything with a count greater than 2 is an issue.

Comment: but out 1900 data I cant enter each name. Country name is just an example. The real sheet consists 1900 names.

Comment: It would be a bit tedious, but is doable. You could look at trying to solve it with relations between tables https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-relationship-between-tables-in-Excel-fe1b6be7-1d85-4add-a629-8a3848820be3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
Other than that I would think it would be solved simpler in a database/

Comment: tried my best..but didn't work the way you suggesting :(